# How can I rotate window configurations among frames?

Tags: window, frames

At work, I have a dual-monitor setup and, naturally, both of them are fullscreened to emacs.  I have bindings to switch between the two frames with `other-frame`, but sometimes I just want particular content on the screen directly in front of me.  (One is off to the side.)  How can I rotate window configurations among frames (in this case, effectively swapping them)?

Comment: To clarify, you want to *keep* the window configurations themselves, but change the frame in which each window configuration is displayed? (I believe you've confused things by referring to "windows" and `other-window` when you meant "frames" and `other-frame`?)

Comment: @phils Oh yes, my mistake. Long day.

Comment: FWIW, I think this would *ideally* be dealt with at the window manager level; as it's a problem which can apply to more than just Emacs. (Not that an Emacs-specific solution isn't useful too, mind.)

Comment: How about just using `set-frame-position` and change the positions of both frames after gathering the current values?  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html

Comment: @lawlist  That's another way of thinking about it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try swapping window states of root windows of the frames in question:

```
(defun swap-frames (a b)
  "Swap window states of root windows of two frames."
  (let ((state-a (window-state-get (frame-root-window a)))
        (state-b (window-state-get (frame-root-window b))))
  (window-state-put state-a (frame-root-window b))
  (window-state-put state-b (frame-root-window a))))

(defun swap-two-frames ()
  "Swap states of the first two frames in frame-list."
  (interactive)
  (swap-frames (nth 0 (frame-list)) (nth 1 (frame-list))))
```

Here's one way to generalize this to implement cyclic rotation of window states.

```
(defun apply-window-states (states windows)
  "Apply states in STATES to all WINDOWS by calling
`window-state-put'."
  (when (< (length states) (length windows))
    (error "not enough window states to apply to all windows"))
  (when windows
    (window-state-put (car states) (car windows))
    (apply-window-states (cdr states) (cdr windows))))
```

This helper function just calls `window-state-put` for all pairs of provided `states` and `windows`.

(There must be a better way to do this. Does Emacs Lisp have `zip`? If it does, we could just map over the result of zipping lists of `states` and `windows` and remove this function.)

Now I can define

```
(defun rotate-frames (arg)
  "Cyclically rotate window states through all frames.
Use the prefix argument to switch direction."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((windows (mapcar (lambda (f) (frame-root-window f)) (frame-list)))
         (states (mapcar (lambda (w) (window-state-get w)) windows)))
    (if (not arg)
        ;; cycle in one direction
        (progn
          (apply-window-states (cdr states) (butlast windows))
          (window-state-put (car states) (car (last windows))))
      ;; cycle in the other direction
      (apply-window-states (butlast states) (cdr windows))
      (window-state-put (car (last states)) (car windows)))))
```

Finally, set some key bindings.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<right>") #'rotate-frames)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<left>") (lambda () (interactive) (rotate-frames t)))
```

I like it. I might actually use this myself. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to extend this to rotate states through all frames?

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yes, certainly. I'll update the answer when I find a moment later today.

Comment: @SeanAllred: I updated the answer. (I think it's pretty neat!)